# 2002 Honda Civic suddenly not starting (with clicking noises) & not responsive to power keys

Tags: honda, starting, civic

Just this morning I drove the car for about 50 miles with no problems at all.  At around 6pm, I entered and tried to start the car, but it wouldn't start:

- There were **loud, weird clicking noises while I tried to start the engine**, and the odometer seemed to be reset (trip A, trip B, not the total one).
- Also, **the speedometer and the oil gauge oscillated**. (Please see video.)
- Finally, **the car seemed to stop being responsive to my power keys**, which definitely still have battery (judged by the small signal light on the key ring).

Here's a video: https://www.dropbox.com/sc/ttcblhk4d97trs5/AABfgaMa8hJyWAyAyK3muWgpa

What could be the problems?  I have little to no experience fixing cars; how should I get someone to help?

**Car is 2002 Honda Civic.  ~120k miles.**  I'm the second owner, owned it for about three years now, never seen this problem.  Please help!

Answer (score 3):

The vehicle battery is not supplying enough power to run the starter. Test the battery and the connections and cables. The video is most helpful.

The clicking is caused by the starter trying to turn and then shutting off due to lack of volatage and this process repeats over and over as long as the key is held in the start position.

Comment: Thanks, Fred!  Your comment is very helpful.  Does this mean the battery is just dead, and replacing it fixes the problems?  Or, does it mean it can be fixed simply by getting a jump start?

Comment: @Covi  I can not tell what has failed without further tests. I would start by testing the battery and its cable connections.